# Convert existing link into node tab

Tags: hooks, navigation

I'm using Organic-Groups on my site and I would like to represent the **unsubscribe from this group** link as a tab after the ***View*** tab.

I am using the following code:

```
function mymodule_menu(){
    $items['group/node/%node/unsubscribe'] = array(
    // $items['node/%node/custom'] = array(
        'title' => 'Custom',
        'access arguments' => array(''),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'weight' => 100,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

That code is copied from a source which works correctly.

Using the original url path (*node/%node/custom*), the tab shows up as expected.

However when i replace the url path with *group/node/%node/unsubscribe*, the tab disappears from my node.

**Can anyone help me implement my group unsubscribe link as a tab, please?**